# DataGridView with ComboBox as one of its column C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have following two tables defined in Access database -

**tblStdTube**
TubeID AutoNunber
TubeOutsideDiameter Number(Double)
TubeThickness Number(Double)

**tblTubeBundle**
TubeBundleID AutoNumber
TubeID Number(LongInteger) // This is a foreign key to tbaStdTube
TubePitch Number(Double)

In C# Form Application, I have created a DataGridView control dgvTubeBundle which is bound to tblTubeBundle. One of the columns of this control which is tied to TubeID, I want to convert to dropdowntype with its source being as following SQL statement -

SELECT TubeID, TubeOutsideDiameter & " x " & TubeThickness AS TubeDiaThk FROM tblStdTube

The data should bind TubeID but list should display TubeDiaThk from above query.

Can anyone help me in designing this kind of form.

Thanks,
Nimish

I am absolutely new to C# forms and intermediate to database.

I have no experience with the form design and have started dipping my toes in the this area.

Comment: The ComboBoxColumn's `DataPropertyName` must be set to `TubeID`, the ComboBox `DisplayMember` to `"TubeDiaThk"` and its `ValueMember` to `"TubeID"`. When you select an Item from the ComboBox, which shows the content of the `TubeDiaThk` Column, you set as value what the `ValueMember` returns, hence the corresponding `TubeID` value -- The DataSource of the ComboBox can be a DataTable or a `List<class>` -- It's not exactly clear why you need a ComboBox, since the relation between the two Tables seems to be 1:1

Comment: I mean, unless you want to load the ComboBox with all the records in `tblStdTube` and the User can actually change the association. If the User cannot change the `TubeID` associated with a record of `tblTubeBundle`, you prefer a JOIN query